# Add CSS to tailwind output that overrides other imported styles

Tags: overriding, tailwind-css

So my basic tailwind stylesheet looks like this

```css
/* Custom Styles */
@import "./spinnerStyles";
@import "./componetStyles.css";
@import "./miscStyles.css";

/* Tailwind Directives */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

which will then output a output.css file.

in my `componetStyles.css` file I added some components classes `.tab` and `.tab.tabSelected` which have some default styling applied.

`miscStyles.css` I use more like a local css file for the current project. So I was expecting I could override the `.tab` and `.tab.tabSelected` classes default styling by making changes to them in `miscStyles.css`

but this doesn't seem to work. componetStyles.css seems to have priority over changes made in `miscStyles.css`.

So far my best solution has been to add the override css code directly under the tailwind directives. But I was hoping for a way to do this by having the override css in a separate file to keep things clean. Is there a way to do this?